# Как поставить Bground с помощью url

Tags: java

Нужна помощь с кодом который писать что бы устанавливался bground с url который указан в коде.
Были попытки сначала загрузить bground на диск и с диска его использовать как bground - не получилось.
Указываю в коде вот так:

```
URL url = new URL("https://medialeaks.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/1465221347128633057-600x338.jpg");
```

не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            URL url = new URL("ссылка на картинку");
            JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(url));
            add(background);
            setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(url)));
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(url);
            ii.getImage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Конечно же разрешение на инет в Манифесте.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

А в коде

```
URL url = new URL("https://medialeaks.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/1465221347128633057-600x338.jpg)";  
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);

ваш_layout.setBackground(image);
```

Comment: Это если ТС про андроид вообще. А если и так, то запрос в сеть из основного потока либо выкинет ошибку, либо заморозит интерфейс. Ну или выкинет ошибку при попытке установить фон не из основного потока.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб речь про swing, как я понимаю)

Comment: Да, речь идёт про swing пишу на ПК (не на андроид)